# Bind Textbox Text to a Static Property

Tags: wpf, binding, static

I have a Static Class with the following Static Property:

```
 public static class PrintingMethods
{
 public static String DocsCountString
    {
        get
        {
            return printDocuments.Count.ToString();
        }
    }}
```

I have a text box that I bind to this property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static  my:PrintingMethods.DocsCountString}" x:Name="PagesNumber"/>
```

This works - I can see the number in the Text, But it never changes If the Property Value Change.

I am quite new to this, I know there are things like Dependency Object and INotify Interface but this won't work for Static.

If anyone can help me with a working code (modification to what I wrote) to Achieve real time textChange that would be great, Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you considered the Singleton Pattern? It works much better for this.

Comment: Can you help me how to do this? Assuming I have a singeltone class, how to I bind the Text to this class property (code if possible)? I will manage the Notify thing in the class, I need the binding Syntax of the text block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer on our comments:
If you use the Singleton Pattern, you can bind to it like that

```
public sealed class MySingleton : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void RaiseProperty(string aPropName)
    {
        // implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
    }

    public static MySingleton Instance 
    { 
        get{ return sInstance; } 
    }

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get {return mMyProperty;}
        set {mMyProperty = value; RaiseProperty("MyProperty"); }
    }

    private string mMyProperty;
    private static MySingleton sInstance = new MySingleton();
}
```

As you can see you can easily use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and implementation with a singleton class. You might want to make the constructor private to disallow creating another instance of this class. Also it would be possible to lazy allocate the MySingleton instance. You will find much more about singletons on stackoverflow.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static  my:MySingleton.Instance}, Path=MyProperty}"/>
```

The important part here now is the Binding and the overriden `Source`. Usually Binding takes the current `DataContext`. By setting a new `Source` the `DataContext` is irrelevant and the new Source is used to get the value behind the `Path` property.

Comment: It gives me an error on the Binding Syntax: "Path was not found in static extension"

Comment: Yes you need that event to implement the interface. This RaiseProperty method is just a convenience method to call this event from the interface, you can name it whatever you like and it only raises the PropertyChanged Event with the given property name. WPFs Binding engine knows this interface, registers itself to this event and waits for you to raise the event. When you do, WPF knows that the property was changed, and will query the value of this property again and update the ui accordingly. Thats how binding to non dependency properties work.

Comment: @meyou yes sorry, that was a little typo. After .Instance the x:Static markup must be closed with a } the Path property is part of the Binding markup. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot, I think I made it!

Answer (score 0):

you should use function in modifier is internal like:

Form2:

```
internal string foo()
{
    return nom;
}
```

Form1:

```
form2 win= new form2();
win.ShowDialog();
Textbox.Text = win.foo();
```

Comment: I don't see how your answer is a answer to the question, could you please explain?